# Spring app error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm launching Spring app locally on my computer and testing it with Postman. I have GET and POST endpoints, and when i'm trying to send any request, i'm getting an HTTP 404 error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists". There is not a single error or warning in Spring app logs-everything looks fine, server up and running on 8080, i even tried to ping it.

Here's my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/note", produces = "application/json")
public class NoteController {
    @Autowired
    private NoteService noteService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/create", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Note> createNote(@RequestBody Note note){
        return new ResponseEntity<Note>(noteService.save(note), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public String getTest(){
        return "test";
    }
    
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
@Data
public class Note {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean isDone;
    private LocalDateTime creationDateTime;
    private LocalDateTime modificationDateTime;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
@Data
public class Tag {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Note> notes;
}
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TodoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>todo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>todo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

POST request: `http://localhost:8080/note/create`

Body:

```
{
    "id": "74ebd665-0fcf-44a9-9dee-35558855e843",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "dbc02c6e-df34-4aea-a0fc-f125612c6163",
            "name": "TAG"
        }
    ],
    "name": "NAME",
    "description": "DESCR",
    "isDone": "false",
    "creationDateTime": "2023-10-18T18:27:32.180454100",
    "modificationTime": "2023-10-18T18:27:32.180454100"
}
```